Optimization error Big integer literals are not available
When I run my Angular project which use mathjs lib, in development mode (HMR, using standard Angular server) it compiles and runs code without any errors. But when I try build dist folder using dev/prod configuration
ng build --configuration=dev

then I get following strange error(s)
Error: Optimization error [main.8ddce6e0bbb9f7d7.js]: ✘ [ERROR] Big integer literals are not available in the configured target environment ("chrome61.0", "edge79.0", "firefox60.0", "ios15.6", "opera110.0", "safari17.4")

    main.8ddce6e0bbb9f7d7.js:219978:14:
      219978 │       if (n < 0n) {
             ╵               ~~
...


Edit file .browserslistrc in main project directory and set browsers verions for which BigInt is available (details here) by updating last line as follows
> 0.5%, last 2 versions, firefox >= 68, chrome >= 67, edge >= 79, not dead

This answer is inspired by this
